# Change bot properties in AIML standard from alicebot.org

Tags: aiml

I'm trying to make a chatbot for a school project. I am using the AIML set 9 from this link.

[Link to AIML Set](https://code.google.com/archive/p/aiml-en-us-foundation-alice/downloads)

I want to change the name of my bot along with the other properties of the bot. But I can't find the place where these properties are set in this set.

Can somebody help me with the code I have to add in the files to set a particular property like bot name="name" or if it's set somewhere then where?

Answer (score 0):

Your bot's name is not located in AIML but in Bot's config folder. Go to config/properties.txt in Alice bot's folder.

In my case, the path is:
bots/alice2/config.properties.txt

Comment: Where is the location? I mean is it inside the project as showed in the link or somewhere else?